# Use of undeclared identifier 'arc4random' after Xcode 4.6 update

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I just ran the Xcode 4.6 update, and now my project will not compile. I had to fix several C++ errors, but one of my C++ files is still getting this one `Use of undeclared identifier 'arc4random'`.

Note that `arc4random()` works elsewhere in the project just fine. (Even in other C++ files!)

I've tried changing it to `arc4random_uniform(1)`, but that doesn't help.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to `#include <stdlib.h>`.

Comment: Nope, thanks, that fixed it! Man, I even tried to search for what I needed to include too. Heh. Why isn't this needed in the other files, I wonder?

Comment: @livingtech: It may be imported already by virtue of being imported by other headers that you're importing. I'm going to bet that you changed your SDK when you updated to Xcode 4.6, and the SDK change is actually what triggered this issue, because the set of headers that you were indirectly importing changed.

Comment: It's certainly included in the other places through an include chain.